# Remove all even numbers from an array

Tags: java

Write the removeEvens() method, which receives an array of integers as a parameter and returns a new array of integers containing only the odd numbers from the original array. The main program outputs values of the returned array.

Hint: If the original array has even numbers, then the new array will be smaller in length than the original array and should have no blank elements.

Ex: If the array passed to the removeEvens() method is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], then the method returns and the program output is:

[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

Ex: If the array passed to the removeEvens() method is [1, 9, 3], then the method returns and the program output is:

[1, 9, 3]

IF I INPUT "[1, 9, 3]," FOR EXAMPLE, I GET "1, 9, 3," INSTEAD OF "[1, 9, 3]" HOW CAN I FIX THIS?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LabProgram {

   public static void printArray(int[] arr){
      int n = arr.length;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static int[] removeEven(int[] arr){
      int oddCount = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
         if (arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            oddCount++;
         }
      }
      int[] result = new int [oddCount];
       int idx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         if(arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            result[idx] = arr[i];
            idx++;
         }
      }
      return result;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
       int[] result = removeEven(arr);
      printArray(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: So, are you asking about the formatting of the print?

Comment: yes, I know I needed to add the '[' but I wasn't sure on how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> IF I INPUT "[1, 9, 3]," FOR EXAMPLE, I GET "1, 9, 3," INSTEAD OF "[1, 9, 3]" HOW CAN I FIX THIS?

The brackets are not added automatically, you are printing elements, there's no reason they would be. You need to modify the printing function.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LabProgram {

   public static void printArray(int[] arr){
      int n = arr.length;
      if (n>0){
        System.out.print('['); //Modified
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
         }
        System.out.print(']'); //Modified   
       }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static int[] removeEven(int[] arr){
      int oddCount = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
         if (arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            oddCount++;
         }
      }
      int[] result = new int [oddCount];
       int idx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         if(arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            result[idx] = arr[i];
            idx++;
         }
      }
      return result;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
       int[] result = removeEven(arr);
      printArray(result);
   }
}
```

This will output the brackets.
Additionally, I'd recommend you modify the code so that the last element in the array does not have a comma after it, I'm leaving that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, you can simply use `Arrays.toString()` from the `java.util` package:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```